# DraggableScrollableSheet Scrolling Problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, draggable

I'm trying to clone the comments section of youtube.
But when I scroll the bottom sheet comments, which should be expand only when I grab the top part of the bottom sheet and pull it, it expands. I hope I was able to explain fully.

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: 0.55,
  maxChildSize: 1,
  snap: true,
  snapSizes: const [
    0.55,
    1,
  ],
  builder: (context, scrollController) => Container(
    color: Color(0xff181818),
    child: ListView(
      controller: scrollController,
      children: [
        customAppBar(context),
        Row(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            filter("All", Colors.white, Colors.black),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            filter("News", Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2), Colors.white),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 45,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 26,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                      child: Text(
                        "R",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                          hintText: "Add a comment...",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                              fontSize: 20)),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              thickness: 1,
              height: 30,
            ),
            comment(),
            comment(),
            comment(),
            comment(),
            comment(),
            comment(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

buildBottomSheet(context) => showModalBottomSheet(
  isDismissible: false,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
  builder: (context) => Sheet(),
);
```

[image: gif]

What can I do so that the comments scroll within themselves and the bottom sheet can only expand when pulled from top of the bottom sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem fixed when I created the bottom sheet with scaffold, created the app bar and list view, gave the app bar a Draggable scroll sheet scrollcontroller and gave a separate scroll controller to the listview.

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: 0.55,
  maxChildSize: 1,
  snap: true,
  expand: false,
  snapSizes: const [
    0.55,
    1,
  ],
  builder: (context, scrollController) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    appBar: PreferredSize(
        child: customAppBar(context, scrollController),
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100)),
    body: Container(
      color: Color(0xff181818),
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              filter("All", Colors.white, Colors.black),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              filter("News", Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2), Colors.white),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 45,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 26,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                    child: Text(
                      "R",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: "Add a comment...",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                            fontSize: 20)),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            thickness: 1,
            height: 30,
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              controller: myScrollController,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) => comment())),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change like `maxChildSize:.55`, and therefore inner snaps can't be bigger than this. setting 1 will provide the draggle to have full screen.

```dart
builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.55,
      maxChildSize: 1,
      snap: true,
      snapSizes: const [
        0.55,
      ],
```

Comment: yes, but  I want to  bottom sheet go to  full screen, when I grab the top part of the bottom sheet to up, just like on youtube.I think this is because of the scroll controller.

Comment: Your default snippet was doing it like setting `maxchildSize:1`, on my test device youTube comment section is able to get 50% height,

Comment: yes, but I don't want the bottom sheet to be full screen when scrolling the comments, I just want the bottom sheet to be full screen when I pull the above part of the bottom sheet upwards.

Comment: does post snippet provide you that UI?

Comment: When I click on the comments button, the bottom sheet opens just like in youtube ui, i think the problem is that I need to give a separate scroll controller to the comments list because it affects the bottom sheet's scroll controls and makes it full screen when scrolled. But I couldn't do that.